# PostgreSQL : Copy Database in same server using a single function

Tags: database, vb.net, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database and my app is coded with VB.NET, For my purpose I do Copy my DB(called `orginladb`) in same server by taking backup of `orginladb` and create new db(`orginladb_copy`) and restore  `orginladb` to `orginladb_copy`

I've written 4 separate code for `Bakcup`,`Drop DB`,`Create DB` and `Restore`,following is the methods

```
/* Backup */
--------
pg_dump  --format=c --username "postgres" originaldb > "D:\Backup\originaldb .backup" 

/*Drop*/
------
psql -U postgres  -d postgres -c "DROP DATABASE  if exists "\"originaldb_Copy"\"" 

/*Create Copy Of Database*/
----------------------------
psql -U postgres  -d postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE "\"originaldb_Copy"\""


/*Restore originaldb.backup to originaldb_Copy*/
---------------------------------------------------
pg_restore  -d originaldb_Copy "D:\Backup\originaldb .backup"
```

So my question is how to copy original db to the same server in a single step or using a single `function` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a method in VB.NET like below

```
Private Sub copy_db()
        Using conn As New NpgsqlConnection("connection_string")
            Dim cmd As New NpgsqlCommand()

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = 'Originaldb';"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            cmd.CommandText = "drop database if exists ""Originaldb_Copy"""
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            cmd.CommandText = "CREATE DATABASE ""Originaldb_Copy"" WITH TEMPLATE ""Originaldb"" OWNER ""owner_name"";"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Sub
```

and call this function where you want to copy `copy_db`

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using the query (however, a DROP has to be done separately):

```
CREATE DATABASE originaldb_Copy WITH TEMPLATE originaldb;
```

Using the "command line" there isn't a shorter way, than the one you've posted, I think.